# Unable to resolve module `react-native-router-flux'

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/MINI_TUTORIAL.md) in my `react-native` android project.

when I run my project, its showing below error on my `emulator`.

[image]

OS : Ubuntu 16.04

**index.android**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,StyleSheet,Text,View,Image} from 'react-native';
import {Scene, Router} from 'react-native-router-flux';

import Movie from './src/view/Movies';


export default class testreact extends Component {
  render() {
      return
      <Router >
        <Scene key="root">
            <Scene key="Movie" component={Movie} title="Movie"/>
        </Scene>
    </Router>
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('testreact', () => testreact);
```

**Movies**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet,Text, View,Image} from 'react-native';
import styles from './../res/styles/style';

var MOCKED_MOVIES_DATA = [
    {title: 'Title', year: '2015', posters: {thumbnail: 'http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg'}},
];
class Movies extends Component {
    render() {
       var movie = MOCKED_MOVIES_DATA[0];
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Title : {movie.title}</Text>
                <Text>Year : {movie.year}</Text>
                <Image source={{uri:movie.posters.thumbnail}} style={styles.thumbnail}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Movies;
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this command : `npm i react-native-router-flux --save`

Answer (score 5):

I started facing this issue and performing the following steps resolved the problem:

1. Change the version of your react-native-router-flux to 3.40.1
2. Remove your node_modules directory (`rm -rf node_modules`)
3. Run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

The problem will on the `import styles from './../res/styles/style';` in **Movies** component replace the above code like this `import styles from '../res/styles/style';`

Answer (score 0):

seems you not downloaded that library please download by following command

```
npm i react-native-router-flux
```

syntax is `npm i <library name>`